# downloading form tag into csv file format

Tags: forms, grails, csv, download, gsp

I need some help or guide on how to download a form into a CSV file. What I'm trying to do here is :

```
      <form>
<select name="mydropdown">
<option value="Chicken">Fresh Milk</option>
<option value="Apple">Old Cheese</option>
<option value="Bread">Hot Bread</option>
</select>
       </form>
     <input type=button>
```

The GSP should be some what look like this and when the csv file is being downloaded, I'm not sure what the controller needs and the result should be one of the values in the options that is being selected and display it as text in the file. By the way I'm using grails. So is there anyone out there can help me with this? I've been researching on it and there isn't any result on this.

Thank you guys so much :)

Comment: No idea what you're asking. By "Download a form into a CSV file" do you mean append form field values to an existing CSV as a row? Later you say "csv is being downloaded" which gives me quite another idea. Text within a form is never submitted, only contents of fields, so `asdasdasd` will not be transmitted.

Comment: Sorry, I've just edited. It should be clearer now. When the user selects one of the option from drop down menu. It downloads one of the option into the csv file.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OpenCSV to do the work.

**Define the dependency**

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile('net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.0')
  ...
}
```

**Create the action**

```
def export() {
  ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  char separator = ';'
  CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output), separator);
  def line = [params.mydropdown]
  writer.writeNext(line as String[]) 
  //use writeNext as many times as needed
  writer.close()
  byte[] bytes = output.toByteArray()
  //needed to force download
  response.setContentType("text/csv")
  response.setContentLength(bytes.length)
  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=mycsv.csv")
  response.outputStream << bytes
}
```

**Change your form to go to export**

```
<g:form action="export">
...
</g:form>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've got a error code and it states : Could not find matching constructor for: liquibase.util.csv.opencsv.CSVWriter(java.io.OutputStreamWriter, java.lang.String). Stacktrace follows:
Message: Could not find matching constructor for: liquibase.util.csv.opencsv.CSVWriter(java.io.OutputStreamWriter, java.lang.String)
Do you know what is this error about?

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much, its fixed already. in the line:
  CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output), ';');

i removed ';' and become
  CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output));
and it worked. I'm not sure why. Do you know?

Comment: It's because must be a char, and groovy defines that as a String. I Will update the example.